# jquery mobile initial first tap / click is registered twice

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a jquery / phonegap app, and everything is good and fast and working except for one small item.    the first initial vclick, tap whatever is picked up twice.  after you have done the first one, everything is okay.   I have tried all sorts like e.preventDefault();  in many places and tried pr-loading pages but still no matter what i always get that initial double click.

here is sample ecmascript

```
$('nav[id="homeList"] div[data-cust="homelink"]').live("vclick",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var over = $(this).attr('data-over');

    if(over !== undefined){ $(this).addClass(over); }
    var pageTo = $(this).attr('data-pagename');

    Log( 'Page to: ' + pageTo );

    if(pageTo !== undefined){
        $.mobile.changePage("#" + pageTo);
        if(over !== undefined){ $(this).removeClass(over); }
    }

    //e.preventDefault();
});
```

here is sample HTML:

```
<div class="ui-listitem">
        <div class="block sprite2 binbox relat" data-pagename="inbox" data-over="binboxover" data-cust="homelink"></div>
     </div>
```

the nav with id of homeList is just my html5  tag that all the ui-listitems sit inside
really puzzled, but am sure someone knows how to maybe cancel out this strange behaviour .

thanks

p.s i have looked at other double click / double event fireing on here but they relate to something that happens over and over, i must stress that this is only for the first time

I have found some sort of fix, but if you click the same location it cancels your click
i have tried setting some kind of global variable but that would mean every tap would have to be registered with the global, so the global holds the last click location and therfor cancelling my initial buttons click location.  have also thought that if there is a global click location then there is no need to check but that wont cancel the first it will just prevent the rest, anyway here is the code that cancels, but prevents:

```
            var lastClick = $( this ).attr( 'data-lastclick' ),
        curClickPoint = e.clientX+'x'+e.clientY
        if( lastClick === curClickPoint) return false;
        $( this ).attr( 'data-lastclick', curClickPoint );
```

okay came up with a final solution:

set a global

```
var hasDoneFirstClick = false;
```

in the same function as above i have used this code:

```
if ( !hasDoneFirstClick ) { 
        hasDoneFirstClick = true;
        return false;
    }
```

it is only the initial click that is doubled so i just ignore the first ever click / tap !

Comment: On which browser does this happen? Could you add an output of console.log(e) please?

Comment: its not on a browser, its a phonegap app, as in phone app Log:
[Session started at 2011-09-15 13:45:32 +0000.]
2011-09-15 14:45:36.214  Device initialization: DeviceInfo = {"name":"iPhone Simulator","uuid":"00000000-0000-1000-8000-0017F234B8FA","platform":"iPhone Simulator","gap":"0.9.6","version":"4.2","connection":{"type":"wifi"}};
2011-09-15 14:47:54.400  [INFO] Page to: homepage
2011-09-15 14:47:54.402 [INFO] Page to: homepage

Comment: Phonegap Build provides a debug mode including a JS console. How does your example perform on regular browsers using click instead of vclick? Is click an option for you?

Comment: cant test in browsers, no browser will allow it to work due to cross domain blah blah, this app wont even work in that browser plugin you can get to emulate iphone.   had click before click is too low down and takes an age to respond the new version of jquery mobile added this vclick event so that it emulates mouse click  or tap  depending on device etc.

Comment: oh and phonegap  i have code to detect connection type etc, lots of hardware hooks so another reason why it wont run in a web browser, has to be hardware no matter what

Comment: but dont think this is actually a phonegap issue, thinks its a jquery one - like preventDefault only works after round 2, and then that results in a single event occurrence... very bizzarre really

Comment: i have this solution:

        var lastClick = $(this).attr('data-lastclick'),
     curClickPoint = e.clientX+'x'+e.clientY
     if( lastClick === curClickPoint) return false;
     $( this ).attr( 'data-lastclick', curClickPoint );

Comment: however if you click the same place, your stuck   hahahahahaha

Comment: I've experienced this issue as well. I think jQuery Mobile is fairly buggy, so I wrote my own touch detection library.

Comment: yeah jquery mobile is bad, i had to write my own CSS and headers and footers and containers made things faster and actually works, just this little niggle grrrr :-)

Comment: fixed:   set a global variable of say var hasHadInitialClick    when a click is registered, check if hasHadInitialClick = false, if it does return false and set to true, from then on everything is fine.:

Comment: what version of jQM are you running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure this answers you question but jQueryMobile in Beta 2 opted to use click instead of vclick. You can read the release notes on this:

- http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/08/03/jquery-mobile-beta-2-released/

Quote:

> **Backtrack: We’ve switched back from vclick to click for links**
>
> In Beta 1, we decided to use our custom vclick event for handling Ajax
>   links to improve responsiveness and to hide the URL bar on the iPhone
>   and Android phones. Even though we did quite a bit of testing before
>   landing this for Beta 1, we began to hear feedback that this change
>   was causing some significant issues out in the wild including:
>
> - Multiple click events causing navigation and form element issue –
>     In    certain situations, when tapping an element, tap/click events
>     seem to    fire twice on links and is due to edge cases where the
>     target of the    touch event and mouse event don’t match due to how
>     the browsers    calculate tolerances for these events. This is most
>     pronounced on    Android 2.1, but affected most WebKit-based browsers
>     to varying    degrees when a tap events occured near the edge of an
>     element.
> - Click handlers in custom scripts didn’t “work” anymore – if a
>     script    bound only to click events on the document, the global
>     vclick feature    could interfere because the touch events may
>     supercede click events    so it events wouldn’t appear to trigger.
>     Based on a lot of detailed    testing and analysis, we’ve decided to
>     roll back to using standard    click events on links instead of using
>     the custom vclick event    because it’s the only reliable way to
>     support all our target    browsers. There are two important things to
>     note in this change:

Comment: hmmm nice find, im on beta 3 and saw no mention of this in the list of events, especial as for every release i always check events and methods to see whats new.....   food for thought   will check it out.

Comment: I was fighting with the same issue (click is registered twice), replacing 'vlick' with 'click' solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old one, but I just ran into it, and in case anybody else does, I traced it to using `$.mobile.changePage` in my `$(document).ready()` which I guess queued up a couple of out-of-sequence events which got sorted out on the first 'real' click.